# PHP Yii1 Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, sql, yii, mariadb

this is my code:

```
TableName::db()->updateAll(array('updated' => 'NOW()'), "WHERE userID
    = ". (string)$id);
```

This is the errormessage i get:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE userID = 1043' at line
>   1. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `TableName` SET `updated`=:yp0 WHERE WHERE userID = 1043;. Bound with :yp0='NOW()'

The SQL Update Query will succesfully executed, but i want to fix this error.

Somebody have a hint for me how to fix this error?

Comment: Looks as though you just need to remove the `WHERE` in `"WHERE userID =`

Comment: Wow that was easy! now it works. Thanks for your help and have a good day .

Comment: The only thing wich didnt worked is that it always enter "01.01.1970 01:00:00" instead of NOW()

Comment: try changing `'NOW'` to `date('d-m-Y H:i:s')`, or any other [php format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
TableName::model()->updateAll(array('updated' =>  new CDbExpression('NOW()')), "userID= ". (string)$id);
```

The SQL Update Query will succesfully. Good luck to you